# applying .on on dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dynamic

I've a snippet of code that runs a ajax request to another script and appending new `<li>`s everytime the more button is being clicked.

I'm using the following code:

```
$(function(){
$('.more').on("click",function(){
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    if(ID){
        $("#more"+ID).html('<img src="moreajax.gif" />');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/cs_directory/helpers/jpost_load_post.php",
            data: "lastmsg="+ ID, 
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("ul#existing_campaign").append(html);
                $("#more"+ID).remove(); // removing old more button

            }
        });
    }else{
        $(".morebox").html('The End');// no results
    }

    return false;
});
});
```

I'm adding the #more button together with the return from my url.

but, since its appended after the document is loaded. My function doesn't seem to apply any longer.. How can i change it so that the more button will act recursively everytime i clicked it?

Comment: check the DOC, they are talking about delegation

Comment: See event delegation using .on() or .delegate(), or you can also clone an existing element using .clone(true, true)

Comment: @A.Wolff No, we haven't enough event delegation questions today :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to delegate the event to parent of elements which are added dynamically

```
$(document).on("click",'.more', function(){
      //your code
});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/).